# Scrapy doesn't crawl all data from page

Tags: web-scraping, python-3.4, scrapy

I have Spider, but it doesn't work.
My spider scraped information from only some links. 
[Here scraping all data](http://price.ua/asus/asus_t100taf-dk001b/catc839t14m911367.html), but [Here nothing](http://price.ua/apple/apple_macbook_pro_md101/catc839t14m352623.html).
I tried scrapping with a different method, but the result is still the same.
Where is my mistake? here's my code so far:

UPDATE: to solve the problem set DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3

```
import scrapy
from NotebookDB.items import NotebookDB

class NotebookDBSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "notebookDB"
    allowed_domains = ["price.ua"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://price.ua/catc839t14.html",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        sites = response.xpath('//*[@id="list-grid"]//div[@class="info-wrap"]/a/@href').extract()
    for site in sites:            
        yield scrapy.Request(site, callback=self.parse_notebook, dont_filter=True)



    def parse_notebook(sels, response):
        item = NotebookDB()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['brand'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="page-title"]/h1//span[@itemprop="brand"]/text()').extract()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="page-title"]/h1/span[1]/span[2]/text()').extract()#response.xpath('//div[@id="page-title"]/h1//span[@itemprop="model"]/text()').extract()
        item['image'] = response.xpath('//a[@id="model-big-photo"]//@href').extract()
        item['price'] = str(response.xpath('//div[@class="price-diapazon"]/span/text()').extract_first()).replace("\u00a0","")
        item['properties'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="relative-wrap"]/text()').extract()[2:-2]

        yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

Your browser engine called by python script is different from the browser you open.

You may need to provide:
1) cookies
2) pass the robot test(if you are not in Ukraine) 
3) Some other information (if they require you to log in)

You can try selenium and you will know the differences.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.